# How can I custom getter templates in AppCode

Tags: intellij-idea, appcode, xcode-template

AppCode can generate getter code like this:

```
- (UIView *)leftAnchorView {
    return _leftAnchorView;
}
```

In the Preferences -> Editor -> File and Code Templates -> Code Tab, I found the getter templates is

```
#if ($IVAR_IS_AVAILABLE == "true")
return $IVAR;#else
return $DEFAULT_RETURN_VALUE;#end
```

So,I modify the templates like this:

```
#if ($IVAR_IS_AVAILABLE == "true")
if(!$IVAR){
    $CUSTOM_CODE
}
return $IVAR;#else
return $DEFAULT_RETURN_VALUE;#end
```

The result is

```
- (UIView *)leftAnchorView {
    if(!_leftAnchorView){
    }
    return _leftAnchorView;
}
```

Now, my target is

```
 - (UIView *)leftAnchorView {
     if(!_leftAnchorView){
         _leftAnchorView = [UIView new];
     }
     return _leftAnchorView;
 }
```

Can anyone tell my how modify the code templates to achive my target? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a description of various variables in the specific template on the bottom-right side of File and Code templates window. So, you need to use a `$RETURN_TYPE` variable, which holds the type. But the type contains `*` which you do not need. In Velocity templates you can use Java String functions, so the final template will be

```
#if ($IVAR_IS_AVAILABLE == "true")
if(!$IVAR){
    $IVAR = [$RETURN_TYPE.replace("*"," ") new];
}
return $IVAR;#else
return $DEFAULT_RETURN_VALUE;#end
```